# AWS EC2 Instance Not Reachable at Port 80 After Adding Route53 Domain + Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a `nodejs` app running on an EC2 instance, with an `iptables` redirect of port 80 to the app's port 3000. This setup was working fine until I added a domain (with Route53) and an Elastic IP. Despite following the [AWS tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/get-a-domain/) for setting up the domain, the instance is no longer responding to requests at port 80.

I've double checked the Security Groups, restarted the instance, as well as re-run the port forwarding commands with `iptables`.

I'm lost as to why this is not working. Is there anything I've overlooked?

Comment: We need more information to help solve this. You should be using the elastic IP - once you have an EIP the original public IP is gone. Public IP field in the console shows the elastic IP. I think you need to go through your question and edit it to be more precise and complete. Ping the elastic IP, try to ssh to it, try http. Your web server may need to be reconfigured to bind to the new IP if you set it up in an odd way. Your security groups and NACLs need to be checked as well.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Tim. I've made a little progress since I posted the question; I'm able to SSH into the instance with the EIP and get HTTP over port 3000. It seems like port 80 is blocked, or not being redirected. I'll be researching the issue some more and will update the question as I make progress.

Comment: Generally you should do all you can yourself, before you ask a question on Server Fault. Once you do ask a question tell us the problem and what you've tried, including the type of information I asked for above.